# Pasta-decorated items in Pesaj

Tags: halacha, passover, chametz-leaven, art

I have a picture frame I made as a kid that's decorated with uncook, dry pasta (and has paint over it).

So far every year I've put it away for Pesaj.

What are the rules and considerations for items that while made of hametz can't be eaten any more?

Comment: You need to get rid of all chametz in your dwelling. I think it means you need to get rid of your picture frame. It might seem hard to separate with it, but if the Master of the Universe commanded it then you have to do it.

Comment: If even a dog wouldn't eat it, then it's not really "chometz." L'chumra, you should still get rid of it, but it's not necessary.

Comment: [Pesachim 45b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=45b&format=pdf)